Distribution of coin tossing - Possible error in solutions?
I've been studying probability theory through the book "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Mathematical Statistics" by V.K. Rohatgi. I've just reached the chapter on random variables, and I either found a mistake in the exercise solutions or I've done one myself. 
The exercise in question asks what the distribution function of a random variable X is. Here, X is the random variable that gives out the number of heads when you throw a fair coin 3 times. What I wrote down on paper is that the distribution gives out $0$ if $x<0$, $\frac{1}{8}$ if $0\leq x < 1$, $\frac{1}{2}$ if $1\leq x < 2$, $\frac{7}{8}$ if $2\leq x < 3$ and $1$ if $x \geq 3$. The author agrees with me in everything except for the value when $2\leq x < 3$, which he says is $\frac{5}{8}$. 
I have no idea why he says it's this value. Can you help me, please?

You are correct. I wouldn't bet money on it, but my guess is that the author knew the step sizes from $2-\to 2+$ and $3-\to 3+$ should match the step sizes from $0-\to 0+$ and $1-\to 1+$, but they left them in the same orders (increase of $1/8$ at $0$ and $2$ and increase of $3/8$ at $1$ and $3$) when they should be reversed (increase of $1/8$ at $0$ and $3$ and increase of $3/8$ at $1$ and $2$).

It could be a typo. The correct answer is certainly 7/8, exactly as you found.

Thank you all very much!
